# How can I pass user settings to Debug adapter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a vscode debug adapter for my programming language, and haven't figured out how to pass configuration options down to debug adapter.

To help me out. Could you explain how to do the following absurd example? I'm just making it clear what I try to achieve.

What should I do to pass variables such as "css.lint.zeroUnits", "explorer.openEditors.visible", "workbench.editor.showTabs"

To a debug adapter so that it can read them when it starts, a debug adapter such as this one: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mock-debug/blob/master/src/mockDebug.ts

There are small number of configuration variables I want to pass, and they all are defined by my extension package, along the debug adapter.

Comment: I guess you figured out how to pass simple types to the debug adaptor (via a custom `DebugConfigurationProvider` instance) which appear in the `args` argument for `launchRequest` or `attachRequest` in your debug adapator. Unfortunately, this doesn' work for objects or functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement [`resolveDebugConfiguration`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DebugConfigurationProvider) you can attach additional fields to the `args` field which is passed to `launchRequest`/`attachRequest`. We use this for a lot of things [in the Dart extension](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/caa7fb31b5d467f7e2e870aa758e4db4d475fe81/src/extension/providers/debug_config_provider.ts#L445-L492) to pass settings and things through:

```
    debugConfig.type = debugConfig.type || "dart";
    debugConfig.request = debugConfig.request || "launch";
    debugConfig.cwd = debugConfig.cwd || (folder && fsPath(folder.uri));
    debugConfig.args = debugConfig.args || [];
    debugConfig.vmAdditionalArgs = debugConfig.vmAdditionalArgs || conf.vmAdditionalArgs;
    debugConfig.vmServicePort = debugConfig.vmServicePort || (isChromeOS && config.useKnownChromeOSPorts ? CHROME_OS_VM_SERVICE_PORT : 0);
    debugConfig.dartPath = debugConfig.dartPath || path.join(this.sdks.dart!, dartVMPath);
```

These [can be read](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/caa7fb31b5d467f7e2e870aa758e4db4d475fe81/src/debug/dart_debug_impl.ts#L109-L110) from the `args` field (which you can use an interface to ensure the fields match up at both sides):

```
protected launchRequest(response: DebugProtocol.LaunchResponse, args: DartLaunchRequestArguments): void {
    if (!args || !args.dartPath || (this.requiresProgram && !args.program)) {
```